# Does POSIX guarantee that all its shell utilities will resolve symbolic links where a file is expected?

Tags: shell, symlink, posix

For POSIX shell utilities which take one or more files as arguments, does POSIX guarantee that a symbolic link can be passed instead (and that the utility will resolve it)? Is it documented somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

POSIX does *not* require that all the utilities it specifies resolve any symbolic link provided as an argument expecting a file name or path. It does however document in detail [how symbolic links should be handled](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_75) (look for the “Symbolic Link” entry).

As a general rule, a path ending in a symlink pointing to a directory must be followed if the path component is suffixed with `/`.

Then

> There are four domains for which default symbolic link policy is established in a system. In almost all cases, there are utility options that override this default behavior. The four domains are as follows:
>
> 1. Symbolic links specified to system calls that take pathname arguments
> 2. Symbolic links specified as command line pathname arguments to utilities that are not performing a traversal of a file hierarchy
> 3. Symbolic links referencing files not of type directory, specified to utilities that are performing a traversal of a file hierarchy
> 4. Symbolic links referencing files of type directory, specified to utilities that are performing a traversal of a file hierarchy

System call behaviour varies for historical reasons.

Utilities *not* traversing a file system follow symlinks, with some exceptions. This covers most utilities:

> The general rule is that the utilities in this category follow symbolic links named as arguments.

Utilities traversing a file system handle symlinks to files other than directories without following them, where that makes sense, and follow them otherwise.

For utilities traversing a file system, POSIX doesn’t mandate a specific behaviour regarding symlinks to directories, but it recommends that the utilities *not* follow symlinks (with detailed reasoning).

There are exceptions to the above, and variations depending on whether the system assigns certain attributes to symlinks (*e.g.* whether symlinks have permissions independent of the file they link to).

Answer (score 0):

That is not a feature that any software needs to support.

POSIX guarantees that when you ask your file system functions (like `open`) to open a symbolic link, you get exactly the file that the symlink points to. (You can explicitly set a flag that makes your attempt to open a file fail if it's a symbolic link. But if you don't that take that extra step, symbolic links act just like the file they point to.)

So that "following" is done by the operating system (e.g., the kernel + libc), the shell utilities don't need to do anything special about symbolic links - unless they're specifically concerned with dealing with non-regular files, in which case I'd expect all of them to deal with the very few non-regular file types there are (if I'm not forgetting something, there's directories, symbolic links, device files, named FIFOs and sockets. That's it.).

Comment: POSIX doesn't specify a "kernel". For software you write, this answer would be correct if you replaced "the kernel" by "the implementation" (of functions like `open`, etc.). But for the standard utilities, they are not defined by source code calling the POSIX.1 interfaces. They're defined more abstractly. So you really need to approach this from the standpoint of Stephen's answer, not system interfaces ("syscalls").

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE you're right, let me fix that.